# How to replace duplicate occurrence of word with numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having a symbol(+) repeated multiple times in a string and need to replace it with numbers in a list.

I tried with this code.

```
test_str = '+ is best . + also has Classes now. \
                + Classes help understand better. '

print("The original string is : " + str(test_str))

repl_dict = {'+' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}

test_list = test_str.split(' ')
res = set()
for idx, ele in enumerate(test_list):
    if ele in repl_dict:
        if ele in res:
            for i in repl_dict[ele]:
                test_list[idx] = repl_dict[ele][i]
        else:
            res.add(ele)
res = ' '.join(test_list)

# printing result
print("The string after replacing : " + str(res))
```

I want to replace the first "+" symbol with 1 and the second "+" symbol with 2 and so on.... What is the best approach. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_str = '+ is best . + also has Classes now. \
                + Classes help understand better. '
repl_dict = {'+' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}


for item in repl_dict:
    cnt=0
    while(item in test_str):
        test_str=test_str.replace(item,str(repl_dict[item][cnt]),1)
        cnt+=1
print(test_str  )
```

have fun :)